# One Asp.Net Core Api Service for Multi-site

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-core, http-headers, httprequest

I want to create only one Asp.Net Core API Service for multiple website. they are almost same but have different content.

i want to know which website call API to return that website's contents.

for example :

Web Site One(angular client) : http://Game.medis.land

Web Site Two(angular client) : http://Tech.medis.land

API(/api/getservices) => return All Services (depend on which site call the API, method return different values)

if Site-One call =>{"previews","reviews"}

if Site-Two call =>{"software","hardware"}

how should i manage this? can i get URL from Header of request? or something else?

Comment: request headers is a nice idea, you could pass some api key there. so backend could create request based on its value. much less flexible approach would be to read Origin header where your website URLs will be mentioned

Comment: thanks,API key is a good Idea.i use this.
But i don't know how to read Origin calling URL. can u give me a hint pleasse?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are many ways that you can handle it:

**1- ClientType**: every clients should introduce theirself for example Client **B** set a header key in all requests (ex: `ClientType:client-b`) and you can determine your clients.

**2- Origin**: you can read the `Origin` from request headers and determine clients by their domains but I think it's not good idea because may be domains changed any times.

**3-Api key**: you can generate a unique key for every clients( `Guid` is a good choice) and clients should set their api key in all request header(ex `api-key: XXXXXXXX`) and in server side determine the clients by key.

Finally I suggest you that handle clients in a middleware and pass it with http features to your controllers.

Comment: Thanks.I think Api key is the best way and i will do this. but now i want to know how to read origin from request?

Comment: You can grab it from the API methods via current HTTP request headers collection:

  ``IEnumerable<string> originValues;
  Request.Headers.TryGetValue("Origin", out originValues)``